# Output is concatenated

Tags: angularjs, meteor, angular-meteor

New click on [Filter] does not clear previous output but adding to exists.
For example, if filtered by "banned" I see the banned users list, next filter by "registered" does not remove the "banned" but adding the "registered" to the end of the table.
In controller $scope.site_users overwritten, but somewhere it still saves the previous filter output. 
Why is that happens? May be something on packages side?

**Installed packages:**

```
urigo:angular - Angular
angularui:angular-ui-router
accounts-password
accounts-ui
twbs:bootstrap
```

**Removed packages:**

```
insecure
autopublish
```

Or in code

**Controller:**

```
angular.module("sis_admin_am").controller("UsersListCtrl", ['$scope', '$meteor',
    function($scope, $meteor){

        $scope.filter = function(){
            $scope.site_users = '';
            $scope.site_users = $meteor.collection(Users).subscribe('site_users_filtered', {status: $scope.userStatus});
        };
    }
]);
```

**View:**

```
<form ng-submit="filter()">
    <button>Filter</button>
    <select ng-model="userStatus" >
        <option ng-selected="selected">banned</option>
        <option>registered</option>
        <option>active</option>
    </select>
</form>
<p></p>
<table class="table">
    <tr class="panel panel-default">
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
    </tr>

    <tr ng-repeat="user in site_users">
        <td>{{ user.username }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.email }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Server part:**

```
Meteor.publish('site_users_filtered', function(options) {
    console.log('options:', options);
    return Users.find(options);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because how Subscriptions in Meteor works.
If you add or change a subscription without closing the ones before, it will just add them all together (which is good but you have to be aware of it).
If you want to filter with subscriptions (for security reasons) you should change your code like that:

```
angular.module("sis_admin_am").controller("UsersListCtrl", ['$scope', '$meteor',
    function($scope, $meteor){

        var savedSubscriptionHandle = null;
        $scope.filter = function(){
            savedSubscriptionHandle.stop();
            $scope.site_users = '';
            $scope.site_users = $meteor.collection(Users);
            $scope.$meteorSubscribe('site_users_filtered', {status: $scope.userStatus}).then(function(handle){
                savedSubscriptionHandle = handle;
            });
        };
    }
]);
```

But if you don't mind keeping all the data in the local cache it might be easier to use Angular's filters or Meteor's cursor syntax to filter the display.

More detailed explanation here:
http://angular-meteor.com/tutorial/step_12

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is, ngSelected NOT necessarly select only one choice of your dropdown.
and that is because,tchnically you should de-select your unwanted userStatus manually as they do in the official doc :

```
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSelected
```

You can try to send your ng-model (userState) along to the filter() function and actually filter with that value directly without having to check the scope.

Comment: About the ngSelected - removed it at all, but issue is still exists. Tried with input type text, but still the same issue. Sorry but not understood about the  ng-model, can you please add an example?